# How to change the reference level based on a combination of levels for running a linear regression

Tags: r, regression, levels, factors

Does any one know how I could use the same relevel method in a linear regression (lm) in order to combine several categorical levels as the reference cell. In my case, my categorical variable of car Type has levels Coupe, Convertable, Wagon, Sedan and Hatchback. In other words, I would like to run a regression model combining reference levels Hacthback, Coupe, Sedan and Wagon, without creating new dummy variables in new columns.

The code below works but only using one reference level. When I try to combine levels ("Sedan" + "Wagon") and run the linear regression it doens't work, it only keeps the first listed as the ONLY reference level.

```
gm$Type = relevel(gm$Type, ref="Sedan")

lm2 <- lm(gm$Price ~ gm$Mileage + gm$Liter + gm$Type)

summary(lm2)
```

As you can see from the output below, Sedan is correctly the omitted and thus the reference level. However, I would like to combine more than one level without creating new objects and going through the dummy variable process.

```
Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         8.617e+03  8.703e+02   9.901  < 2e-16 ***
gm$Mileage         -1.848e-01  2.605e-02  -7.097 2.82e-12 ***
gm$Liter            5.092e+03  2.020e+02  25.210  < 2e-16 ***
gm$TypeConvertible  1.914e+04  8.980e+02  21.309  < 2e-16 ***
gm$TypeCoupe       -3.260e+03  5.791e+02  -5.629 2.51e-08 ***
gm$TypeHatchback   -3.902e+03  8.358e+02  -4.669 3.56e-06 ***
gm$TypeWagon        7.465e+03  8.326e+02   8.966  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6042 on 797 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6291,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6263 
F-statistic: 225.3 on 6 and 797 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Are you saying you want coupes, hatchbacks, sedans and wagons put into a single category and then assigned to the reference category?  If so, this seems like a good candidate for `levels`.  As in `levels(gm$Type) = c("Convertible", "other", "other", "other", "other")` (based on whatever order the levels are in).  Then you could set the reference level to whatever you like with `relevel`.  The `levels` help page has a lot of good examples.